# how to change aspectRatio option with RWD in chartjs?

Tags: charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I want to change this setting according to the width of the screen

```js
// min-width:576px
aspectRatio: 1

// min-width:1280px
aspectRatio: 2
```

I hope you can recommend me how to handle this setting change better, and I simply want to change this setting and not change to other CSS . thank you all！

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `aspectRatio` option in your configuration as a scriptable option where you can return the value coming from your logic, accessing to screen size or CSS and checking the value of min-width:

```
options: {
  aspectRatio(ctx) {
    // your logic
    return yourValue;
  },
  .... 
}
```

Comment: it will work!
```
aspectRatio() {
      return window.innerWidth > 576 ? 2 : 1;
    },
```

Comment: and i want to ask , how can i change tooltip font-weight?

Comment: having a look to the doc https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html, you can see there is 3 tooltip options where you can change the font: titleFont, bodyFont and footerFont. Here is the doc how to configure fonts: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html